# Ajuda para criar função que localiza texto em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando criar um userscript para eu Digitar minha senha ao invés de ficar clicando no teclado numérico que o site exige.

O problema é que cada botão corresponde a 2 números aleatórios, então eu preciso fazer com que a função identifique o número dentro do atributo Title de um dos botões.

Por exemplo esse é o teclado que apareceu agora:

```html
<img src="/V1/ITAUF/IMG/teclado_tecla.gif" border="0" width="46" height="46" alt="" title="0 ou 2">
<img src="/V1/ITAUF/IMG/teclado_tecla.gif" border="0" width="46" height="46" alt="" title="1 ou 3">
<img src="/V1/ITAUF/IMG/teclado_tecla.gif" border="0" width="46" height="46" alt="" title="4 ou 6">
<img src="/V1/ITAUF/IMG/teclado_tecla.gif" border="0" width="46" height="46" alt="" title="8 ou 9">
<img src="/V1/ITAUF/IMG/teclado_tecla.gif" border="0" width="46" height="46" alt="" title="5 ou 7">
```

Então supondo que minha senha seja 5821 primeiro eu iria separar cada caractere da senha que digitei:

```js
var senha  = prompt("Digite sua senha de Internet");
var t = senha.length;
var i = 0;
```

Daí agora que preciso descobrir qual o botão correspondente ao caractere para clicá-lo, pensei em algo com expressões regulares:

```js
while (i < t){
l = senha.substr(i,1);
$('img[title="[i]"]').click(); //Clica no botão que foi encontrado o caractere pela expressão regular
i++;
}
```

Mas não obtive sucesso, estou meio perdido em como posso fazer alguém me da uma dica?

grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta:

```
while (i < t)
{
  l = senha.substr(i,1);
  if ($('img')[i].title.indexOf(l) !== -1)
  {
    $('img')[i].click();
  }
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado a ideia é por aí mesmo, mas o site do banco tem algum bloqueio que não deixa o userscript funcionar direito, então no fim não vai dar certo por isso.